# Apache RewriteCond not fully working

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache as a web server to rewrite urls. The pattern is simple:

```
if request starts with "/services" then
  rewrite is off
else
  using ssl. replaces http with https
```

So i have my own solution:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services.* [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Also i separate access logs by urL , one is ssl access logs and the other is none ssl access logs . What I want see is the none ssl access logs contains request only start with services .But i have found some requests in none ssl access logs likes this:

```
10.75.6.22 - - [28/Mar/2012:08:38:08 +0800] "GET /validate/showValidateProgress.jsp?
10.186.96.70 - - [28/Mar/2012:09:01:48 +0800] "GET /vjsp/confirm.jsp?
```

The requests not start with /services should using ssl unfortunately my configuration file is not working . But there is still some requests in ssl access logs which means some of the request satisfy my expectation . 
  I am very confuse about the logs and can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```
# if request starts with "/services" then rewrite is off
RewriteRule ^/services - [QSA,NC,L]
# using ssl. replaces http with https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Compare the logs I understands that all the request in none access logs has a http code 302! That means the first request is none ssl, and then redirected to https. So both your and mine configuration are right! Thank you Olivier!